# Highlight matches in MongoDB full text search

Tags: database, mongodb, search, indexing, full-text-search

Is it possible to define which part of the text in which of the indexed text fields matches the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know and can tell from the Jira, [no such feature exists currently](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13532). You can, of course, attempt to highlight the parts of the text yourself, but that requires to implement the highlighting and also implement the [stemming](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#text-search) according to the rules applied by MongoDB.

The whole feature is somewhat complicated - even consuming it - as can be seen from the [respective elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Refer to Mongodb Doc Highlighting](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/full-text-search/highlighting/)

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
  {
    $searchBeta: {
      "search": {
        "path": "description",
        "query": ["variety", "bunch"]
      },
      "highlight": {
        "path": "description"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "description": 1,
      "_id": 0,
      "highlights": { "$meta": "searchHighlights" }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that solution applies only to MongoDB Atlas at the moment @LF00.